# using compareTo method JAVA

Tags: java

Having trouble in my computer science class:
You will need to update Time (see below) so that it implements the Comparable interface. This will require adding an implements statement to the class declaration as well as the compareTo method. Then, you will need to add a difference method to the class. These two methods' requirements are as follows:
compareTo(Object other):Returns -1 if current time is less than other.Returns 0 if current time is equal to other.Returns 1 if current time is greater than other.

String difference(Time t): Returns a String holding the difference between the current time and the Time t passed in via parameter. All values should be positive, and in the format: 
    //08:09 
    //10:35
To test your code, run the runner class (see below). You will need to change the runner to test with other values to make sure your program fits all the requirements.

Sample Run of student_runner_time.java:

1712

0945

Greater than:
1

Less than:
-1

Times equal:
0

Hours equal:
1

-1

Difference

00:11

00:11

00:00

Time:

```
public class Time implements Comparable
{
 private int hour;
 private int minute;

/*
 * Sets the default time to 12:00.
 */
public Time ()
{
     this(12, 0);
}

/*
 * Sets hour to h and minute to m.
 */
public Time (int h, int m)
{
     hour = 0;
     minute = 0;
     if (h >=1 && h <= 23)
          hour = h;
     if (m >= 1 && m <= 59)
          minute = m;

}

/*
 * Returns the time as a String of length 4 in the format: 0819.
 */
 public String toString ()
 {

      String h = "";
      String m = "";
      if ( hour <10)
           h +="0";
      if (minute <10)
           m +="0";
      h += hour;
      m+=minute;

      return "" + h + "" + m;
 }

 public int compareTo(Object other){

   if(t1<t2){
  return -1;
 }
   else return 0;
  }   
 String difference(Time t){




   return "";

     }
}



student time runner:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class student_time_runner
{

 public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException
 {

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  // time 1
  Time t1 = new Time(17, 12);
  System.out.println(t1);

   Time t2 = new Time(9, 45);
  System.out.println(t2);
  System.out.println("Greater Than:");
  System.out.println(t1.compareTo(t2));
  System.out.println("Less Than:");
  System.out.println(t2.compareTo(t1));
  System.out.println("Times equal:");
  Time t3 = new Time(9, 45);
  System.out.println(t3.compareTo(t2));
  System.out.println("Hours equal:");
  Time t4 = new Time(8, 45);
  Time t5 = new Time(8, 34);
  System.out.println(t4.compareTo(t5));
  System.out.println(t5.compareTo(t4));
  System.out.println("Difference");
  System.out.println(t4.difference(t5));
  System.out.println(t5.difference(t4));
  System.out.println(t4.difference(t4));
 }// main

}// class
```

Comment: Do you have any question for us?

Answer (score 1):

Your compareTo method does not really a comparison. It should rather be like this

```
  public int compareTo(Object other){

     int timeDiff = this.getHour()*60 + this.getMinute() - other.getHour()*60 - other.getMinute();

     if(timeDiff>0){
         return -1;
     }
     if(timeDiff<0){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you have to add both getters for sure.